# How to check wether $interval is called with exact arguments or not in sinon.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, sinon-chai

I want to test whether the callback function of $interval is getting called or not after a certain time interval. But I am getting the argument list as empty. I don't know why.

Below is the code which contains $interval -

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var app = angular.module("AppModule");

    app.controller("cntrl", cntrl);

    /*@ngInject*/
    function cntrl($scope, $state, $interval, utils) {

        var vm = this,
            data,
            timer,
            i;

        init();

        function init() {
            _createList();
        }

        /*Refreshing list after each 30 second interval*/
        timer = $interval(function() {

            utils.getObjectList()
                .then(function(data) {
                    utils.data = data;
                });

            init();

        }, 1000);

        /*Cancelling interval when scope is destroy*/
        $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            $interval.cancel(timer);
        });

        function _createList() {

            //some code            

        }
    }

})();
```

Below is the unit testing for it -

```
describe.only("Unit Controller: cntrl", function() {
    "use strict";

    // Angular injectables
    var $q, $httpBackend, $injector, $controller, $rootScope, $state, $location, $templateCache, $compile, $interval;

    // Module defined (non-Angular) injectables
    var $scope;

    // Local variables used for testing
    var vm;

    // Initialize modules
    beforeEach(function() {
        module("AppModule");
    });

    beforeEach(function() {

        var templateHtml;

        inject(function(_$q_, _$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$state_, _$location_, _$templateCache_, _$compile_, _$interval_) {
            $q = _$q_;
            $controller = _$controller_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $location = _$location_;
            $state = _$state_;
            $templateCache = _$templateCache_;
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $interval = _$interval_;

            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            templateHtml = $templateCache.get("/modules/list.html");

            $compile(templateHtml)($scope);
        });

    });

    beforeEach(function() {

        vm = $controller("cntrl", {
            $scope: $scope
        });

    });

    it("Should call the list API continuosly after a certain interval", function() {

        var fn = function() {

            utils.getObjectList()
                .then(function(data) {
                    utils.data = data;
                });

            init();

        };

        var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
        var mySpy = sinon.spy($interval);
        var throttled = throttle(mySpy);

        throttled();

        clock.tick(999);
        console.log(mySpy);
        expect(mySpy.notCalled).to.be.true;

        clock.tick(1);
        expect(mySpy.called).to.be.true;

        expect(intervalSpy.calledWith(fn)).to.be.true; //This is failing

        console.log(intervalSpy.getCall(0).args); //this shows empty. 

        function throttle(callback) {
            var timer;
            return function() {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    callback.apply(this, args);
                }, 1000);
            };
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Where is `intervalSpy` created?

Comment: @tasseKATT it is named as mySpy in my code.